# Receive image file through rest Api

Tags: java, rest, multipartform-data, jersey-2.0, form-data

How to receive an image file through Rest APIs. There is an option of MULTIPART_FORM_DATA which looks like it will send files in parts as in more than one request.
I want to receive images very fast on server. around 2 images per second.

Comment: Please have at look at this [help page](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) on how to ask a good question: you question is too vague, and does not provide any example of what you have tried.

Comment: using base64 format

Comment: Thanks @CSK base64 turns out to  be a good option.

Answer (score 2):

Simply read image in a `File` and use `Response` class to build the response.

```
Response.ok(new File("myimage.jpg"), "image/jpeg").build();
```

There are other variations of the same.

Read the image using following.

```
URL url = new URL("http://localhost:8080/myimage/1");
URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();

input = connection.getInputStream();
byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
int n = - 1;

OutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("Output.jpg" );
while ( (n = input.read(buffer)) != -1) 
{
    fos.write(buffer, 0, n);
}
fos.close();
```

You can use Apache HTTP client to make it prettier.

Comment: I want to receive the image at server side.
I am planning to use @FormDataParam. Is there any other efficient way.

Comment: You just have to use an HTTP client to download the file. There's nothing different from reading a simple `inputstream`

Comment: @sunder, I thought you wanted to call a REST api, for uploading image `@FormDataParam` is alright.